# How to check if Apache compression is working?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, compression

I just added the following to my Apache config file:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

How do I check if it is actually working? Nothing on the browser tells me if the page contains gzipped content.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An alternative way to quickly check the headers of the HTTP response would be to use **curl**.

For instance, if the *Content-Encoding* header is present in the response, then *mod_deflate* works:

```
$ curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://www.example.org/index.php
[...]
Content-Encoding: gzip
[...]
```

If you run the above command without the *-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'* part, which implies that your HTTP client does not support reading compressed content, then *Content-Encoding* header will not be present in the response.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should be able to replace `-H ..` with `--compress`.

Comment: I confess I totally missed that one! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Please note that if you dont use `-I` option, there is a difference between `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'` and `--compress`. The last one **decompresses** the output content. (check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365089/162178)

Answer (score 18):

for simple way, you can use google chrome, open menu Tools > Developer Tools
then look at this image
[image]

if you DISABLE the compression, you won't see that gzip text

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can help with this. Fire it up and look at the Inspector. It can also tell you what file sizes you're looking at. Additionally, you can set it to decode automatically if you are running into [compression-related problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454572/why-does-my-ie-progress-bar-keep-going-after-every-other-page-load) with your browser.

Note: this answer is now CW--please update with more info if you wish (I don't have time right now!)

Comment: +1 Fiddler. You should perhaps add some detail about what to look for in the Inspector.

Comment: @Dan: I'd love to but can't make the time right now. Please feel free to contribute if you can (it's CW now)

Answer (score 1):

I use the [HTTP Compression tool](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/) at whatsmyip.org regularly.

Another solution is to use Lynx. Easy to install on Linux from repos and I think you can get Windows versions too. Just run the command:

```
lynx -head -dump "http://www.example.com/page.html"
```

Then check if there is a line saying `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a web service I created specifically for this purpose. I wanted an easy way to check for gzip (on all of a site's resources) without having to dig into inspector or using browser plugins.

[gzipWTF - easiest way to check for gzip](http://gzipwtf.com)

Answer (score 0):

The [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) Firefox extension is your friend.  You can examine the "Content-Encoding" header and look for "gzip".

Answer (score 0):

If you use Safari with the develop menu enabled you can use the web inspector
[image: Web inspector]

The web inspector graphically shows page load times and file sizes so you can test before you enable compression, record the sizes and then test after and compare.

Screeshot via the webkit.org blog.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for firefox. It can show you the response headers, which is very helpful in debugging other problems too.

For example:

```
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2009 08:46:30 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 6446
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

200 OK
```

.. which clearly tells that response was gzipped. The headers are also very useful in debugging problems with other header-related things, such as eTags and expires.